# Grammar books with exercises and answer key for autonomous study of Dutch

Tags: resource-request, physical-resources, grammar, dutch

I am looking for a grammar book or series of grammar books for Dutch that match the following criteria:

- the book or books must be in Dutch, i.e. all grammar rules and instructions must be in Spanish (not English, German, French, Spanish, ...);
- content should be organised in chapters that first explain a set of grammar rules and then provide a number of exercises that apply these rules;
- there must be an answer key (the answer key may be a separate volume);
- the book must be appropriate for self study (the presence of an answer key is not sufficient; some books of this type are intended for teachers of Dutch).

I am looking for books for the levels A2 - B2. The first three criteria may be easy to fulfil, but the last criterion is essential and it may not be obvious whether a book matches this criterion just by looking at the book cover in an online bookshop. Answers that are based on personal experience using such books would be especially appreciated.

It does not matter whether the books were published in the Netherlands or in Belgium, since grammatical differences between the two countries are negligible or non-existing.

Answer (score 1):

The following books were published in the Netherlands:

- *Vlekkeloos Nederlands, Taalbeheersing A2. (Taalniveau 1F en 2F*). Uitgeverij Pak. [ISBN 9789077018569](http://www.uitgeverijpak.nl/boeken-nederlands/vlekkeloos-nederlands/taalbeheersing-a2). Answer key (*Antwoordenboek*): ISBN 9789077018569-A.
  This set of books covers the spelling of verbs, spelling in general, punctuation, style, parts of speech and phrases. Each chapter contains exercises.
- *Vlekkeloos Nederlands, Taalbeheersing B1 (Taalniveau 2F)*. Uitgeverij Pak. (256 pages) [ISBN 9789077018590](http://www.uitgeverijpak.nl/boeken-nederlands/vlekkeloos-nederlands/taalbeheersing-b1). Answer key (*Antwoordenboek*): ISBN 9789077018590-A. In addition to grammar rules, this book also covers spelling, style and punctuation. Each chapter contains exercises.
- *Vlekkeloos Nederlands, Taalbeheersing B2 (Taalniveau 3F en 4F)*. Uitgeverij Pak. (244 pages) [ISBN 9789077018309](http://www.uitgeverijpak.nl/boeken-nederlands/vlekkeloos-nederlands/taalbeheersing-b2). Answer key (*Antwoordenboek*): ISBN 9789077018309-A.
  In addition to grammar rules, this book also covers spelling, style and punctuation. Each chapter contains exercises.